# Joomla timetable component

Tags: joomla, components

I've been lookinfg for few hours in JED, google and polish joomla center, but I cant find anything like this.. I need a timetable component for Joomla. It should look more or less like this: http://www.salsapicante.pl/grafik - on the bottom. I'm sure they are not creating it manually..
I found some complicated calendar components, but they all have features I dont need and I can disable.. I just need simple table that client can edit from the backend without using html.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I use JCal pro, it's one of the best calendar components and very reasonably priced.

Here is one of my client sites using JCal - http://mckinneyacademy.com/mckinney-calendar/200

Comment: Thanks, I found it recently. I think I'll use this one